# Changing file extension in Python

Tags: python, rename, file-extension

Suppose from `index.py` with CGI, I have post file `foo.fasta` to display file. I want to change `foo.fasta`'s file extension to be `foo.aln` in display file. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

[`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), [`os.rename()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)

for example:

```
# renamee is the file getting renamed, pre is the part of file name before extension and ext is current extension
pre, ext = os.path.splitext(renamee)
os.rename(renamee, pre + new_extension)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, i saw documentation before too but didn't work.

Comment: Use the first function to get the base. Combine it with the new extension and pass the old filename and the new filename to the second function.

Comment: actually, its better to use this method instead for python3:    pathlib.path(pathtofile).with_suffix(".mynewext"). The way, suggested with pathlib.path(pathtofile).stem works but will delete the path before the basename.

Comment: str(pathlib.path(pathtofile).with_suffix(".mynewext"))

Comment: There's no real need for assigning a variable to the original extension.
I find this is more straightforward: os.rename(filename, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.aln')

Answer (score 139):

An elegant way using [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths):

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('mysequence.fasta')
p.rename(p.with_suffix('.aln'))
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't ask to perform a rename, it was in the tags, and if you're going to perform a rename and if it's possible the input might have a path and not just a filename, this technique is the right one.

Comment: Regarding `.with_suffix()`, the properties `.suffix` and `.suffixes` should have setters.

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems like `.suffix` is read-only, at least as of 3.9.5.

Comment: @Jesse Paths are immutable https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#general-properties

Answer (score 86):

```
import os
thisFile = "mysequence.fasta"
base = os.path.splitext(thisFile)[0]
os.rename(thisFile, base + ".aln")
```

Where thisFile = the absolute path of the file you are changing

Comment: I like this answer more because it provides an example and not just cites the methods needed to accomplish the task.  Thanks @FryDay

Comment: `base, _ = os.path.splitext(thisFile)` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 28):

Starting from Python 3.4 there's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) built-in library. So the code could be something like:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = "mysequence.fasta"
new_filename = Path(filename).stem + ".aln"
```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem

I love pathlib :)

Comment: This is even better with python 3.6 string interpolation syntax ( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ )

`new_filename = f"{Path(filename).stem}.aln"`  

Comment: Be careful - stem also strips the path if one is present. If you wanted to rename the file and if a path was supplied (which admittedly it wasn't in the question), this technique would fail.

Comment: Also, the result is a string, no longer a pathlib Path.  `p.parent / (p.stem + '.aln')` will give you a new Path.

Comment: Warning: Path(filename).stem drops the directory (prefix) part of the filename.

Answer (score 22):

Use this:

```
os.path.splitext("name.fasta")[0]+".aln"
```

And here is how the above works:

The splitext method separates the name from the extension creating a tuple:

```
os.path.splitext("name.fasta")
```

the created tuple now contains the strings "name" and "fasta".
Then you need to access only the string "name" which is the first element of the tuple:

```
os.path.splitext("name.fasta")[0]
```

And then you want to add a new extension to that name:

```
os.path.splitext("name.fasta")[0]+".aln"
```

Answer (score 11):

As AnaPana mentioned pathlib is more new and easier in python 3.4 and there is new with_suffix method that can handle this problem easily:

```
from pathlib import Path
new_filename = Path(mysequence.fasta).with_suffix('.aln')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pathlib and preserving full path:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('/User/my/path')
new_p = Path(p.parent.as_posix() + '/' + p.stem + '.aln')
```

Comment: to make it just a little bit simpler `new_p = Path(p.with_suffix('').as_posix() + '.aln')`

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, I experienced a case of multiple dots on file name that splittext does not worked well... my work around:

```
file = r'C:\Docs\file.2020.1.1.xls'
ext = '.'+ os.path.realpath(file).split('.')[-1:][0]
filefinal = file.replace(ext,'')
filefinal = file + '.zip'
os.rename(file ,filefinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> file = r'C:\Docs\file.2020.1.1.xls'
>> ext = '.'+ os.path.realpath(file).split('.')[-1:][0]
>> filefinal = file.replace(ext,'.zip')
>> os.rename(file ,filefinal)
```

Bad logic for repeating extension, sample: 'C:\Docs\.xls_aaa.xls.xls'