# How can I replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?

Tags: python, filenames, scons, strip

Is there a built-in function in Python that would replace (or remove, whatever) the extension of a filename (if it has one)?

Example:

```
print replace_extension('/home/user/somefile.txt', '.jpg')
```

In my example: `/home/user/somefile.txt` would become `/home/user/somefile.jpg`

I don't know if it matters, but I need this for a SCons module I'm writing. (So perhaps there is some SCons specific function I can use ?)

I'd like something **clean**. Doing a simple string replacement of all occurrences of `.txt` within the string is obviously not clean. (This would fail if my filename is `somefile.txt.txt.txt`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting extension from filename in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: SCons allows getting at the filebase in an action string.  Can you post your scons specific logic that needs this? Is this for the action, emitter, scanner?

Comment: some of this doesn't seem to work any more as path returns a PosixPath not a string  :p

Comment: Python 3.9 will allow `path.removesuffix('.txt') + '.jpg'`, which will likely be the easiest way going forward https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/

Comment: @panofsteel What import is needed for that?

Comment: @not2qubit None, `removesuffix` is a string method: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix edit: so to clarify, in panofsteel's example, `path` is just a string

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Try [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) it should do what you want.

```
import os
print os.path.splitext('/home/user/somefile.txt')[0]+'.jpg'  # /home/user/somefile.jpg
```

```
os.path.splitext('/home/user/somefile.txt')  # returns ('/home/user/somefile', '.txt')
```

Comment: Only put the new name together with os.path.join to look clean.

Comment: @Tony Veijalainen: You shouldn't use os.path.join because that is for joining path components with the OS-specific path separator. For example,
`print os.path.join(os.path.splitext('/home/user/somefile.txt')[0], '.jpg')` will return `/home/user/somefile/.jpg`, which is not desirable.

Comment: Explict is better than implicit. If there is zero or one suffix then: `pathlib.Path('/home/user/somefile.txt').with_suffix('.jpg')`

Comment: Won't this break if there is more than one dot in the file name, e.g. if the file is called `some.file.txt`? Can anyone provide solution for this case?

Comment: @Garnagar filename = filename.rsplit( ".", 2 )[ 0 ] + ".txt"

Answer (score 250):

Expanding on AnaPana's answer, how to **remove** an extension using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (Python >= 3.4):

```
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> filename = Path('/some/path/somefile.txt')

>>> filename_wo_ext = filename.with_suffix('')

>>> filename_replace_ext = filename.with_suffix('.jpg')

>>> print(filename)
/some/path/somefile.ext    

>>> print(filename_wo_ext)
/some/path/somefile

>>> print(filename_replace_ext)
/some/path/somefile.jpg
```

Comment: Real Python has a good write-up of example use cases of the pathlib module: https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/

Comment: This answer is my typical approach, but it seems to fail when you have multiple file extensions. For example, `pth = Path('data/foo.tar.gz'); print(pth.with_suffix('.jpg'))` will output `'data/foo.tar.jpg'`. I suppose you can do `pth.with_suffix('').with_suffix('.jpg')`, but it's clunky, and you would need to add an arbitrarily long chain of `.with_suffix('')` calls in order to deal with an arbitrary number of dots `.` in a file extension (admittedly, more than 2 is an exotic edge case).

Comment: @tel You could use a `while` loop to solve that: `pth = Path('data/foo.tar.gz'); while pth != pth.with_suffix(''): pth = pth.with_suffix(''); pth = pth.with_suffix('.jpg')`

Comment: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56807917/5299417) for a solution to the multiple extensions problem.

Comment: @tel: Note that your `pth.with_suffix('').with_suffix('.jpg')` handles both the double suffix *and* the single suffix case, in one line.

Answer (score 62):

As @jethro said, `splitext` is the neat way to do it. But in this case, it's pretty easy to split it yourself, since the extension *must be* the part of the filename coming after the final period:

```
filename = '/home/user/somefile.txt'
print( filename.rsplit( ".", 1 )[ 0 ] )
# '/home/user/somefile'
```

The `rsplit` tells Python to perform the string splits starting from the right of the string, and the `1` says to perform at most one split (so that e.g. `'foo.bar.baz'` -> `[ 'foo.bar', 'baz' ]`). Since `rsplit` will always return a non-empty array, we may safely index `0` into it to get the filename minus the extension.

Comment: Note that using `rsplit` will result in different results for files which start with a dot and have no other extension (like hidden files on Linux, e.g. `.bashrc`). `os.path.splitext` returns an empty extension for these, but using `rsplit` will treat the whole filename as an extension.

Comment: This will also give unexpected results for the filename `/home/john.johnson/somefile`

Comment: not to mention cases where you have filename.original.xml

Answer (score 24):

I prefer the following one-liner approach using [str.rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit%20%22str.rsplit()):

```
my_filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '.jpg'
```

Example:

```
>>> my_filename = '/home/user/somefile.txt'
>>> my_filename.rsplit('.', 1)
>>> ['/home/user/somefile', 'txt']
```

Comment: This fails if the somefile has no extension and user is 'john.doe'.

Comment: Wouldn't they all fail then?

Answer (score 17):

## Handling multiple extensions

In the case where you have multiple extensions using `pathlib` and `str.replace` works a treat:

### Remove/strip extensions

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/path/to/myfile.tar.gz")
>>> extensions = "".join(p.suffixes)

# any python version
>>> str(p).replace(extensions, "")
'/path/to/myfile'

# python>=3.9
>>> str(p).removesuffix(extensions)
'/path/to/myfile'
```

### Replace extensions

```
>>> p = Path("/path/to/myfile.tar.gz")
>>> extensions = "".join(p.suffixes)
>>> new_ext = ".jpg"
>>> str(p).replace(extensions, new_ext)
'/path/to/myfile.jpg'
```

If you also want a `pathlib` object output then you can obviously wrap the line in `Path()`

```
>>> Path(str(p).replace("".join(p.suffixes), ""))
PosixPath('/path/to/myfile')
```

### Wrapping it all up in a function

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

PathLike = Union[str, Path]


def replace_ext(path: PathLike, new_ext: str = "") -> Path:
    extensions = "".join(Path(path).suffixes)
    return Path(str(p).replace(extensions, new_ext))


p = Path("/path/to/myfile.tar.gz")
new_ext = ".jpg"

assert replace_ext(p, new_ext) == Path("/path/to/myfile.jpg")
assert replace_ext(str(p), new_ext) == Path("/path/to/myfile.jpg")
assert replace_ext(p) == Path("/path/to/myfile")
```

Comment: pathlib has a shortcut for this: Path().with_suffix("") will remove an extension and Path.with_suffix(".txt") will replace it.

Comment: Correct. But it only removes the first extension. So in the above example, using `with_suffix` instead of `replace` would only remove `.gz` instead of `.tar.gz`

My answer was intended to be "general", but if you only expect a single extension, `with_suffix` would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Fittingly, from Python 3.9 onward, you can use `removesuffix` over `replace`. This is perhaps safer, e.g. on Linux some *directories* might have a `.d` suffix: `"/home/config.d/file.d".replace(".d", "")` -> `'/home/config/file'` versus `"/home/config.d/file.d".removesuffix(".d")` -> `'/home/config.d/file'`. So, also saves the `""` function argument.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @AlexPovel, I have added an example using `removesuffix` for python 3.9

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR:**
Best way to replace all extensions, in my opinion, is the following.

```
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz')
print(p.with_name(p.name.split('.')[0]).with_suffix('.jpg'))
```

**Longer Answer:**
The best way to do this will depend on your version of python and how many extensions you need to handle. That said, I'm surprised nobody has mentioned pathlib's `with_name`. I'm also concerned that some answers here don't handle a `.` in the parent directories. Here are several ways to accomplish extension replacement.

## Using Path Objects

### Replace Up to One Extension

```py
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo')
print(p.with_suffix('.jpg'))
```

### Replace Up to Two Extensions

```py
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo.bar')
print(p.with_name(p.stem).with_suffix('.jpg'))
```

### Replace All Extensions

Using pathlibs `with_name` (best solution, in my opinion):

```py
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz')
print(p.with_name(p.name.split('.')[0]).with_suffix('.jpg'))
```

Using `functools.reduce` and pathlib's `with_suffix`:

```py
import pathlib
import functools
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz')
print(functools.reduce(lambda v, _: v.with_suffix(''), p.suffixes, p).with_suffix('.jpg'))
print(functools.reduce(lambda v, e: v.with_suffix(e), ['' for _ in p.suffixes] + ['.jpg'], p))
```

**Python 3.9+** Using pathlib and str.removesuffix:

```py
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path('/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz')
print(pathlib.Path(str(p).removesuffix(''.join(p.suffixes))).with_suffix('.jpg'))
```

## Without Using Path Objects (Strings Only)

In general, I think solutions using pathlib are cleaner, but not everybody can do that. If you're still using python 2, I'm sorry. If you don't have the pathlib package for python2, I'm really sorry.

### Replace All Extensions

Python 2.7 compatible using `os.path`:

```py
import os
ps = '/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz'
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(ps), os.path.basename(ps).split('.')[0] + '.jpg'))
```

**Python 3.9+** Using `removesuffix` and `os.path` (if you have python3.9, why aren't you using `pathlib`?):

```py
import os
ps = '/path/to.my/file.foo.bar.baz.quz'
print(ps.removesuffix(os.path.splitext(ps)[-1].split('.', 1)[-1]) + 'jpg')
```

Comment: This is what I used, as it seems to be the best answer here that doesn't need python 3.9

Comment: Thanks. You caused me review my answer, fix my original answer to handle more than two extensions, and add several alternatives, including python3.9 answers. I'm not sure that 3.9 actually makes things any simpler. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your last 2.7 version example seems broken, as "ps.removesuffix" as a string method was only introduced with 3.9 version, and both answers are exactly equal. Edit error?

Comment: @Welsige Thanks. You're right, I just copied over the wrong example from my test file. Should work now.

Comment: Please don't forget to also show the output from each of your suggested solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do is to use the [`str.rpartition(sep)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) method.

For example:

```
filename = '/home/user/somefile.txt'
(prefix, sep, suffix) = filename.rpartition('.')

new_filename = prefix + '.jpg'

print new_filename
```

Answer (score 7):

For Python >= 3.4:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = '/home/user/somefile.txt'

p = Path(filename)
new_filename = p.parent.joinpath(p.stem + '.jpg') # PosixPath('/home/user/somefile.jpg')
new_filename_str = str(new_filename) # '/home/user/somefile.jpg'
```

Comment: I think the pathlib approach suggested by JS. is much simpler.

Comment: Agreed `.stem` is the simplist answer