# How can I extract a file name with dat extension in python?

Tags: python, file, io

There are many files in a folder like

sample-file.dat host-111.222.333.444.dat win.2k3.dat
hello.micro.world.dat

I was using split

```
 file = os.path.basename(path) 
filename = file.split(".")[0]
```

but it does not work for all files, is there a better way to read whole filename even with dots and ignore only .dat extension

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if file.endswith('.dat'):
    filename = file[:-4]
```

`file[:-4]` means get the string `file` and remove the last four characters

Alternatively, see this question for more answers: [How to replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python)

Comment: why are we using file[:-4] ?

Comment: @leanjohnlearner That means removing the last four characters (`.dat` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
>>> s = "host-111.222.333.444.dat"
>>> filename = s[:s.rfind(".")]
>>> filename
'host-111.222.333.444'
```

It's like `find()`, but it returns the highest index.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

if they have multiple points, slice and recombine with join !

```
file = os.path.basename(path) 
filename = ".".join(file.split(".")[:-1])
```

This will remove what's after the last point, without checking the content,i.e.

- a.b.c => a.b
- a.b.dat => a.b
- a.exe => a
- .emacs => error ?
- a.b.c. => a.b.c