# Extracting all file names in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a application that converts from one photo format to another by inputting in `cmd.exe` following:  "AppConverter.exe" "file.tiff" "file.jpeg"

But since i don't want to input this every time i want a photo converted, i would like a script that converts all files in the folder. So far i have this:

```
  def start(self):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\converter"):
     for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".tiff"):
          subprocess.run(['AppConverter.exe', '.tiff', '.jpeg'])
```

So how do i get the names of all the files and put them in `subprocess`. I am thinking taking basename (no ext.) for every file and pasting it in `.tiff` and `.jpeg`, but im at lost on how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Comment: Unfortunately, that thread doesn't help me much, granted i am beginner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fastest way would be to use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module for expressions:

```
import glob
import subprocess

for file in glob.glob("*.tiff"):
    subprocess.run(['AppConverter.exe', file, file[:-5] + '.jpeg'])
    # file will be like 'test.tiff'
    # file[:-5] will be 'test' (we remove the last 5 characters, so '.tiff'
    # we add '.jpeg' to our extension-less string
```

All those informations are on the post I've linked in the comments o your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into os.path.splitext(). That allows you to split the file name into a tuple containing the basename and extension. That might help...

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html