# Adding extension to multiple files (Python3.5)

Tags: python, rename, file-extension

I have a bunch of files that do not have an extension to them.

```
file needs to be file.txt
```

I have tried different methods (didn't try the complicated ones since I am just learning to do a bit of advanced python).

here is one that I tried:

```
import os
pth = 'B:\\etc'
os.chdir(pth)
for files in os.listdir('.'):
  changeName = 'files{ext}'.format(ext='.txt')
```

I tried the append, replace and rename methods as well and it didn't work for me. or those don't work in the 1st place with what I am trying to do?

What am I missing or doing wrong?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `os.rename`. But before that,

1. Check to make sure they aren't folders (thanks, AGN Gazer)
2. Check to make sure those files *don't* have extensions already. You can do that with `os.path.splitext`.

---

```
import os
root = os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir('.'):
   if not os.path.isfile(file):
       continue

   head, tail = os.path.splitext(file)
   if not tail:
       src = os.path.join(root, file)
       dst = os.path.join(root, file + '.txt')

       if not os.path.exists(dst): # check if the file doesn't exist
           os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: @AGNGazer Good idea!

Comment: I would also add a check that the destination file does not exist, possibly printing a warning but proceed instead of crashing...? Couldn't edit previous suggestion to add "warning" to it. But we should leave something to OP to do :)

Comment: should be os.getcwd() not os.getcwd('.')
other than that. awesome. thank you.