# How do I add extensions to files using python in multiple subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add a .jpg extension to around 300K pictures.  They are all in 12 sub-directories and four more subdirectories in each of those 12.

I tried following this post but didn't do a walk down to all subdirectories:
[Adding extension to multiple files (Python3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540785/adding-extension-to-multiple-files-python3-5)

I also tried the following:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Photos'
genmod = os.walk(path)

for path, pathnames, files in gen_obj:
    for file in files:

        head, tail = os.splitext(file)
        if not tail:
            src = os.path.join(path, pathnames, file)
            dst = os.path.join(path, pathnames, file + '.jpg')

            if not os.path.exists(dst): # check if the file doesn't exist
                os.rename(src, dst)
```

The above runs but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure it runs? there are several errors

Comment: Well I’ll say that it gives no error message.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that's the case

Comment: You should use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library and should be used instead of `os`.  [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above runs but nothing happens.

I doubt that, there are 2 problems:

- `os.splitext` should be `os.path.splitext`
- `os.path.join` should not be given `pathnames`, so

  ```
  os.path.join(path, pathnames, file)
  ```

  should be

  ```
  os.path.join(path, file)
  ```

  and

  ```
  os.path.join(path, pathnames, file + '.jpg')
  ```

  should be

  ```
  os.path.join(path, file + '.jpg')
  ```