# Edit a given variable in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script that removes duplicate of a file which is given by `-i` parameter to the script. So like `-i input.txt`.

I want the `-o` parameter, which is the output filename, be like this: `input-file-name-without-extension_dupsremoved.txt`. Like `-o input_dupsremoved.txt`.

#### removeDups.py

```
import optparse


def removeDups(inputfile, outputfile):
        file1 = open(inputfile, "r")
        lines = file1.readlines()
        file1.close()
        out = open(outputfile, "w")
        out.writelines(uniquelines(lines))
        out.close()


def uniquelines(lineslist):
        unique = {}
        result = []
        for item in lineslist:
        if item.strip() in unique: continue
        unique[item.strip()] = 1
        result.append(item)
    return result

def main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog ' +\
                        '-i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
        parser.add_option('-i', dest='inputfile', type='string',
                        help='specify your input file')
        parser.add_option('-o', dest='outputfile', type='string',
                        help='specify your output file')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
       inputfile = options.inputfile
        outputfile = options.outputfile
        if (inputfile == None) or (outputfile == None):
                print (parser.usage)
                exit(1)
        else:
                removeDups(inputfile, outputfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Im currently using this batch file to do it but the batch file is not correct.

```
@echo off
set /p input= Input file: 
set output= output.txt
set dupsremoved= %input%_dupsremoved.txt
script1.py -i %input% -o %output%
script2.py -i %output% -o %dupsremoved%
del %output%
```

which can be fixed by this answer from Gerhard Barnard:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "input=Input file: " 
set "output=output.txt"
set "ext=%input:*.=%
set "input=!input:.%ext%=!
set "dupsremoved=!input!_dupsremoved.txt"

script1.py -i %input% -o %output%
script2.py -i %output% -o %dupsremoved%
del %output%
```

Comment: Why use a batch file for this? Why not Python?

Comment: Good idea! Didnt think of it. You know how to do it?

Comment: @aria. Give it a shot and ask another question when you hit a wall so to speak

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python/42288083

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using your batch file, then here you go. This method uses `delayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "input=Input file: " 
set "output=output.txt"
set "ext=%input:*.=%
set "input=!input:.%ext%=!
set "dupsremoved=!input!_dupsremoved.txt"

script1.py -i %input% -o %output%
script2.py -i %output% -o %dupsremoved%
del %output%
```

Also note the issues in your script, for instance the spaces after the `=` in the set command. if you have whitespace in the set command, they will be in your value as well.

Comment: please delete or add to comments, I edited the whole Question. Thanks for answer btw.

Comment: No, your initial requirement was to do it in batch, I put in the effor to post the answer, so it will remain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change `input.txt` into `input_dupsremoved.txt` you can use the following code:

```
txt1 = "input.txt".split(".")[0]
txt2 = txt1 + ("_dupsremoved.txt")
```

For these kind of operations I recommend looking at the official documentation for strings: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html