# Is there a way to remove the extension from all files in a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following up on this SO question

[How to replace (or strip) an extension from a filename in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python)

I have about a hundred files in a folder, all of which I would like to remove the extension from the name. Is there a way to do this without having to change each individual file?