# how to remove folder path from a string in python

Tags: python

I have tried this code but it didnt work how to remove the path from String.help me to remove the path of directories from the string

```
string=""
count=0
for file in glob.glob(r'G:\\songs\\My Fav\\*'):
    string=string+"{}. {}\n".format(count,file)
    count+=1
string=string.replace("G:\\songs\\My Fav\\","")
print(string)
```

OUTPUT for above code is :

```
0. G:\\songs\\My Fav\0001.mp3
1. G:\\songs\\My Fav\0002.mp3
2. G:\\songs\\My Fav\0003.mp3
3. G:\\songs\\My Fav\0004.mp3
4. G:\\songs\\My Fav\0005.mp3
```

**But i need output without the path, like this below**

```
0. 0001.mp3
1. 0002.mp3
2. 0003.mp3
```

```
string=string.replace("G:\\songs\\My Fav\","")
```

and this above line i have tried shows error

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-to-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python

Comment: don't escape the backslash if you're passing a raw string. just run `for file in glob.glob(r'G:\songs\My Fav\*'):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because `\` escapes the next character, so the `replace` is actually looking for single `\` and not doubles `\\`.

You can use `split`

```
string.split("\\")[-1]
```

Maybe cleaner would be to use `os.path.basename` to extract the file name. Cf the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly duplicated, but I don't have a link, try this:

```
import os
os.path.basename(string)
```

`os.path` has specialized functions dedicated to manipulating paths.

Answer (score 0):

yes its worked,i have tried like this . thank you so much

````
import os
string=""
count=0
for file in glob.glob(r'G:\\songs\\My Fav\\*'):
    file=os.path.basename(file)
    string=string+"{}. {}\n".format(count,file)
    count+=1
print(string)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try **indexing**?
it is bit long process but it is easy to understand and replicate.

like this -

```
print(stirng[17:]) # I counted the them so you don't have to count.
```

Comment: no its not worked    string="185. G:\\songs\\My Fav\Yogi_B_&_Natchatra_-_Madai_Thiranthu_featurin’_Mista_G(256k).mp3"
print(string[17:])