# XLSB to CSV with pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Trying to convert multiple XLSB files to CSV. Not sure what is the problem here

```
import os

import pandas as pd

path = r'C://Users//greencolor//Autoreport//Load_attachments//'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("PB orders"):
        print(filename)                         #until here its working
        month = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")
        print(month)                            # I get the error here
        month = month[month['Sales Manager'] == 'DEVON, JOHN'] #filtering by manager
        month.to_csv (path + filename + ".csv", index = None, header=True)
```

Error

> **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PB orders Dec.xlsb'**

Why I get this error? print(filename) is printing all the XLSB files that name starts with PB orders

Comment: That means the file path is wrong. `filename` is just the file name, not the full path. You need to combine it with the root path to get the actual full path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filename` is just the file's name, not the full path. You need to combine it with `path` to get the full path to the file. You can do that in a safe manner with [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=path%20join#os.path.join) :

```
import os
...
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.startswith("PB orders"):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
        print(full_path )                         
        month = pd.read_excel(full_path , sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")
```

**Searching with a pattern**

An alternative is to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to search for files that match a pattern. You still need to generate the full path:

```
import glob

...

for filename in glob.glob("PB orders*.xlsb", root_dir=path):
    full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    print(full_path )                         
    month = pd.read_excel(full_path , sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")
```

**Avoiding temp files**

You still need to check the file name to avoid the temporary files generated when someone opens an Excel file (the files that start with `~`) :

```
for filename in glob.glob("PB orders*.xlsb", root_dir=path):
    if not os.path.basename(filename).startswith("~"):
        full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
            print(full_path )                         
            month = pd.read_excel(full_path , sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, but how should I change the last part where it converts to CSV?

Comment: basically i want to keep the original name ( PB orders December) but the extension should be csv

Comment: @Greencolor there are several answers for this, eg [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-can-i-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python). Most of the answers work if the filename contains only one dot. pathlib's `with_suffix` can be used to change the extension no matter what the rest of the filename contains

Comment: is not it possible to do with `df.to_csv`?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `month = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")` try to replace it with this:

`month = pd.read_excel(path + filename, sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb")`

This will prepend the path to your filenames in the given directory.