# Python Pathlib: "with_suffix" - Object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I am trying to write a small program to find all audio files in a specific folder (and subsequent subfolders), then check if that audio file already has a .vtt or an .srt file associated with it, and if not, it should create a list of said audio files. This list is then passed to a program to create transcriptions. Here is my code so far:

```
import pathlib
import posixpath

# Search for all audio files, recursively
extentions = [".ogg", ".wav", ".mp3"]
folder_path = "/tmp/audiofiles/"
files = [f for f in pathlib.Path(folder_path).rglob('*') if f.suffix in extentions]


for x in files:
    abs_name = posixpath.abspath(x)
    print(abs_name)
    filename_without_ext = abs_name.with_suffix('')
    print(filename_without_ext)
```

The `abs_name` comes back as `/tmp/audiofiles/2/2.ogg`. So I am trying to test if `/tmp/audiofiles/2/2.vtt` or `/tmp/audiofiles/2/2.srt` exists, and if not, add `/tmp/audiofiles/2/2.ogg` to a the list.

I have looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548673/how-can-i-replace-or-strip-an-extension-from-a-filename-in-python), especially the answer by JS, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_file_list.py", line 15, in <module>
    filename_without_ext = abs_name.with_suffix('')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'with_suffix'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `posixpath.abspath` gives strings, not Path objects.

Comment: From `help(posixpath)`: *"Instead of importing this module directly, import os and refer to
    this module as os.path."*

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to mix `pathlib` and `posixpath` here; the moment you call a `posixpath` method on a `Path`, you get back a `str`, not a new `Path`. `Path` objects generally have the same functionality as what `os.path` (`posixpath` is just a non-Windows-specific module supporting `os.path`) offers, so you just use the equivalent `Path` method instead. In this case, you don't have to do the complete refactor your performed, all you need to do is change:

```
abs_name = posixpath.abspath(x)
```

to:

```
abs_name = x.absolute()
```

As a side-note: While `posixpath` is *technically* documented, it's needlessly non-portable to use it directly. When you do need that functionality (and don't want `pathlib`'s high-level `Path` objects), use `import os.path` instead.

Comment: Note that `Path.absolute` only works on 3.11 and up. A method by that name *exists* on earlier versions, but it was undocumented, buggy, and not something people were actually supposed to use.

Comment: Also, `os.path.abspath` normalizes the resulting path, while `Path.absolute` doesn't, so there can be important behavior differences, especially in the presence of symlinks and `..` path components.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners like me, who may need something like this in future, this is how I solved this part of my problem.

```
import pathlib
import os

def generate_file_list():
    # Search for all audio files, recursively
    extentions = [".ogg", ".wav", ".mp3"]
    folder_path = "/tmp/audiofiles/"
    files = [f for f in pathlib.Path(folder_path).rglob('*') if f.suffix in extentions]
    to_be_transcribed = []

    for x in files:
        filename_vtt = x.with_suffix('.vtt')
        filename_srt = x.with_suffix('.srt')
        x = str(x)
        if os.path.isfile(filename_vtt) or os.path.isfile(filename_srt):
            print('File: ' + x + ' has a transcription already')
        else:
            to_be_transcribed.append(x)

    return to_be_transcribed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list = generate_file_list()
    print(file_list)
```