# How to convert all files (in different formats) in given folder to different file type

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder with many images from different types (png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, pdf), and I would like to convert them all into png (for instance) using imagemagick.

Is there a single command which can perform this? If not, what should I do instead?

Thanks.

Comment: or if you use python look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900035/changing-file-extension-in-python

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel the post you linked is not helpful. It details how to rename a file, not how to reformat it entirely.

Comment: @speedstyle oeww nasty, back in the days I didn't really know stuff... . I will let my command stand, so other people will learn from the mistake.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try the `mogrify` command:

```
mogrify -format png *.*
```

But be careful. Without the `-format` option, `mogrify` overwrites the original images. Make sure to read the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).

Comment: Thanks.  I get the following error massage: 
C:\Users\Tal\s>mogrify -format png *.*
mogrify.exe: unable to open module file `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.
3-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_INI_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/mo
dule.c/GetMagickModulePath/683.
mogrify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `desktop.ini' @ error/cons
titute.c/ReadImage/550.

(Is this simple to resolve?)

Comment: That's because `mogrify` tries to convert the file `desktop.ini` which isn't an image file. You should only pass image files to `mogrify`. Either delete `desktop.ini` or change `*.*` to a wildcard that only matches the image files in your directory. You can also run the command several times for every file format: `mogrify -format png *.jpg`, `mogrify -format png *.bmp`, etc.

Comment: I'd like to merge different image file types into **a single `*.pdf`** file. How to adapt your code to make that work?

Comment: I guess I could revert to other tools like `pdftk` (e.g. by using `pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf`), but would rather have a one-liner to get the whole job done...

Comment: If `mogrify` is used with the `-format` option, the file is not replaced, but a new one is saved with the new prefix.

Comment: If mogrify is used with the `-format` option using the original file format it will still overwrite the original. Not sure if there's anyway to avoid this.

Answer (score 40):

Although `mogrify` seems to do the job, I would like to show you how this can be done with multiple commands with `convert` from ImageMagick.

I think multiple commands are better, because the number of file types is supposedly quite small and you can better adjust it to your needs:

This command:

```
for file in *.xbm; do convert $file "`basename $file .xbm`.png"; done
```

will convert all `.xbm` files to `.png` while not touching the xbm files.

Then you can move all "converted" files:

```
mkdir converted
for file in *.xbm; do mv $file converted/; done
```

Comment: The current command does not work if the filename contains spaces. One way to fix this is `for file in *.xbm; do convert "$file" "\`basename \"$file\" .xbm\`.png"; done` but I have a feeling that bash offers a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: For the second step just do `mv *.xbm converted`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `convert` command from ImageMagick package, e.g.

`find . -maxdepth 1 \( -iname \*.png -o -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.jpeg -o -iname \*.bmp -o -iname \*.pdf \) -exec convert -verbose "{}" "DEST_DIR/{}.png" \;`

Or if you've got all the files in the same directory, try the following simpler way:

```
convert '*.*' converted_%04d.png
```

Similar: [How can I scale all images in a folder to the same width?](https://askubuntu.com/q/135477/78223)