# Renaming file extension in Python 2.7

Tags: python, rename

I am trying to rename the extension of a text file to zip as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900035/changing-file-extension-in-python).
The file is being written based on a base64 encoded response from a server, which I am decoding before writing.

This is my code snippet:

```
f = open("response.txt","wb")
f.write(json.loads(response.text)['Binary'].decode('base64'))
f.close()
file1 = "C:\Users\xyz\response.txt"
base = os.path.splitext(file1)[0]
os.rename(file1, base + ".zip")
```

I am getting the following error even though the file is in the absolute path specified in my code:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Please assist.

Comment: `print base + ".zip"`

Comment: `print os.path.exists(file1)`

Comment: You have received correct answers below, but I'll leave the above comments.  When you run into a bug, start testing your assumptions.  Something as simple as print-statements can do the job for small scripts.  Had you run those print-statements you would have detected the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
file1 = "C:\Users\xyz\response.txt"
```

"\r" is a single character representing a carriage return. You probably don't have a file that has a carriage return in its name. If you intended that to be a backslash followed by an R, use raw strings.

```
file1 = r"C:\Users\xyz\response.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
file1 = "C:\Users\xyz\response.txt"
```

to this:

```
file1 = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\response.txt"
```

or this:

```
file1 = r"C:\Users\xyz\response.txt"
```