# How to very easily split filename and append date/time?

Tags: python, regex, split

Let's say I have:

```
attachment.FileName = "hello.pdf"
```

I would like for it to result in:

```
hello_July5.pdf
```

I know how to get the date what I am appending, but how do I easily make a split between the "." and then add the variable `date` between it?

I know this is simple, I am just looking for the quickest fix possible.

Comment: Split using dot, then do `arr[0] + '_' + month + '.' + arr[1]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing file extension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900035/changing-file-extension-in-python) in spirit not exact context.

Answer (score 1):

In an ugly, code-golf way:

```
("_" + myDate + ".").join(filename.split("."))
```

If you want something more readable:

```
filePieces = filename.split(".")
newFilename = "{0}_{1}.{2}".format(filePieces[0],myDate,filePieces[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = 'test.pdf'
print(os.path.splitext(name))
# ('test', '.pdf')
```

From there you can append the date in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a regex, but `os.path` will be more reliable.

```
import os.path
from datetime import date

def add_date(fname, day=date.today()):
    return day.strftime('_%b%d').join(os.path.splitext(fname))
```

In the format string, `%b` represents the three-letter abbreviation of the month, and `%d` the numerical representation of the day of the month.

[demo](https://repl.it/JsXm/1)

Answer (score 0):

### [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sypkrX/1)

```
(^.*)(\.[^.]+$)
```

### Description

```
 1st Capturing Group (^.*)
   ^ asserts position at start of a line
   .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
     * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 2nd Capturing Group (\.[^.]+$)
   \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
     Match a single character not present in the list below [^.]+
   + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
   $ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Answer (score 0):

**pathlib** is a nice way of handling pathnames, filenames and directories.

**arrow** is nice for handling various date and time calculations.

Preliminaries:

```
>>> class Attachment:
...     pass
... 
>>> attachment = Attachment()
>>> attachment.FileName = 'hello.pdf'
>>> import pathlib
>>> import arrow
```

Create the required date. Split it into its component pieces in `p`. Assemble the required pieces, including a suitably formatted date into the new filename.

```
>>> a_date = arrow.get('2017-07-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
>>> p = pathlib.PurePath(attachment.FileName)
>>> attachment.FileName = p.stem + a_date.format('_MMMMD') + p.suffix
>>> attachment.FileName 
'hello_July5.pdf'
```