# Change file extension from .tar.gz to .tgz in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), is there a simple solution to change a file extension with two suffixes like ".tar.gz" to a simple suffix like ".tgz".

Currently I tried:

```py
import pathlib

src = pathlib.Path("path/to/archive.tar.gz")
dst = src.with_suffix("").with_suffix(".tgz")
print(dst)
```

I get:

```
path/to/archive.tgz
```

This question is related but not identical to [Changing file extension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2900035/1513933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is using path lib a requirement?

if not, the os module would work just fine:

```
import os

path_location = "/path/to/folder"
filename = "filename.extension"

newname = '.'.join([filename.split('.')[0], 'tgz'])

os.rename(os.path.join(path_location, filename), os.path.join(path_location, newname))
```

EDIT:

found this on the pathlib docs:

```
PurePath.with_suffix(suffix)¶
```

Return a new path with the suffix changed. If the original path doesn’t have a suffix, the new suffix is appended instead. If the suffix is an empty string, the original suffix is removed:

```
>>>
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('c:/Downloads/pathlib.tar.gz')
>>> p.with_suffix('.bz2')
PureWindowsPath('c:/Downloads/pathlib.tar.bz2')
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('README')
>>> p.with_suffix('.txt')
PureWindowsPath('README.txt')
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('README.txt')
>>> p.with_suffix('')
PureWindowsPath('README')
```

EDIT 2:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('path/to/tar.gz')
new_ext = "tgz"
filename = p.stem
p.rename(Path(p.parent,  "{0}.{1}".format(filename, new_ext)))
```

Comment: No, using **pathlib**…

Comment: Actually, this was my first attempt.

Comment: wouldve been helpful to know the methods you attempted before making this ticket. Try my second EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You could rename it.

```
import os
old_file = os.path.join("directory_where_file", "a.tar.gz") 
new_file = os.path.join("directory_where_file", "b.tgz") 
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: No, using **pathlib**…

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('path/to/tar.gz')
name_without_ext = p.stem
p.rename(Path(p.parent,  name_without_ext + '.' + new_ext))
```