# How can I iteratively modify excel filetypes using win32com and os?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to iterate over a directory that contains a number of xlsm (Macro-enabled excel) files, opening each file and saving as an xlsx file. Ideally, I would have three directories, one that holds my script, one where the unmodified files live, and another where the modified files will be saved.

The directory, macro_dir, contains: 'test1.xlsm', 'test2.xlsm', 'test3.xlsm'

I cannot get my code to work when I loop through each file in the directory. Code chunk A (below) works: In the excel.Workbooks.Open method, the file variable was an absolute path to one of the xlsm files and the wb.SaveAs method contained an absolute path with the new filename and extension.

**A. Working code:**

```py
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\Documents\macro_dir\test1.xlsm')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs(r'C:\Users\Documents\macro_dir\output1.xlsx', FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
excel.Application.Quit()
```

**B. My attempt at turning this into a loop:**

```py
import os
import win32com.client as win32

dir = r'C:\Users\Documents\macro_dir'

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

for file in os.listdir(dir):
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
    wb.CheckCompatibility = False
    wb.SaveAs(file[:-4] + 'xlsx', FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2)
    excel.Application.Quit()
```

I expected code chunk B (above) to modify each .xlsm file and save them as .xlsx to the same directory. However, the code produces the following error:

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find test1.xlsm. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

EDIT: I cannot simply change the file extension, the file format must be converted by opening the file in excel and saving as an .xlsx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing file extension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900035/changing-file-extension-in-python)

Comment: It seems that those answers just change the file extension, rather than the format. This will not work with macro-enable excel files as I have tried it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your for loop that is causing the error, not `win32com`. You aren't using the full path.

This should fix it.

```
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    file = os.path.join(dir, file)
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file)
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much, kicking myself for this one.

Comment: No problem. Been there, sometimes you just need a pair of fresh eyes