# Raster to ASCII Conversion

Tags: python, windows, ascii, raster, file-conversion

I am trying to convert my TIFF files into ASCII files. I have a code written out that is doing exactly what I need done BUT when it converts it to an ASC file, it puts ".tif" on the end of the original file name - which I can't have.

```
import os
dir_name = 'C:\\PRCPRaster'
for filename in os.listdir(dir_name):
    if not filename.endswith(".tif"): continue
    full_path = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)
    outASCII = '%s.asc' % (full_path)
    arcpy.conversion.RasterToASCII(full_path, outASCII)
```

I have tried to debug my current code but haven't had any such luck. I'm sure its a simple fix but I'm still pretty new to python and would love some assistance if anyone has an easy fix for me!

Comment: You check that finename ends with .tif, then construct full_path with that filename that ends with .tif.  Remove .tif first.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm sorry I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly, would you be willing to help me though?

Comment: The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900035/changing-file-extension-in-python) has multiple examples